# Cast Field as Decimal Inside Multiple Replace's and Substring

Tags: t-sql, substring, sql-server-2016, data-conversion

I'm trying to import customer data from a legacy vendor to our database - and the prior vendor was a varchar(10) field where I have seen characters such as ")" and "(" and "-".

I am trying to import to our table which stores a phone number in two columns - phone1AreaCode and phone1Number.  phone1AreaCode is a decimal(3,0) data type and phone1Number is decimal(7,0).

I've tried various ways of casting or convert the substring to a decimal but I keep running into errors.

Here is what I have that works in a SELECT but fails when I try to INSERT:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(PHONE,1,3),'(',''),')',''),'-',''),' ','') AS phone1AreaCode,
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(PHONE,4,7),'(',''),')',''),'-',''),' ','') AS phone1Number ,
```

Error:

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

I've tried various placements of the CAST or CONVERT but they are all giving me the same error:

```
Argument data type decimal is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.
```

Failed attempt:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CAST(PHONE AS DECIMAL(3,0)),1,3),'(',''),')',''),'-',''),' ','') AS phone1AreaCode,
```

From Googling, it looks like maybe SUBSTRING cannot deal with a decimal data type.  If that is true, how could I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by first converting the field to an INT and then converting that to a DECIMAL:

```
CASE
    WHEN s.PHONE IS NULL OR s.PHONE = '' THEN NULL
    ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,0),CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(PHONE,1,3),'(',''),')',''),'-',''),' ','')))
END AS phone1AreaCode,

CASE
    WHEN s.PHONE IS NULL OR s.PHONE = '' THEN NULL
    ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,0),CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(PHONE,4,7),'(',''),')',''),'-',''),' ','')))
END AS phone1Number,
```